# JNLP jar update

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

In the JFXtras project (http://jfxtras.org) we use webstart to start the Ensemble demo app. However, updates to the Ensemble.jar are not detected. I've tried to use versioned jars as described here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/avoidingUnnecessaryUpdateChecks.html

and even used different filenames each time by adding a timestamp to the name of the jar (this is not using versioning as above):

<jar href="Ensemble_20121020a.jar" download="eager" />

But it keeps using the jar it originally downloaded. I've verified that it uses the new JNLP file each time. Especially that last approach, using a completely different href should have worked. How in the world did webstart detect that this is the same file as the original Ensemble.jar it downloaded before?

Comment: *"I've verified that it uses the new JNLP file each time."*  How?

Comment: By opening the JNLP file that was downloaded in an editor

Comment: Thanks for the info.  After using versioning, that was the only thing I could think of that might cause the caching.. :(